# Why is the cookie being set on the frontend domain?

Tags: reactjs, go, next.js, cookies, jwt

I am running a golang server at `localhost:8080`
and nextjs server at `localhost:3000`

When you make a `POST` request to `localhost:8080/login`, it authenticates and sets a cookie.

When I send a `POST` request to the `/login` route on the backend, I got a cookie on the `localhost:3000` which is the frontend(as I can see on my browser). Why is the cookie being set on the frontend domain?

[image: Browser Screenshot]

I am using the following options on the backend

```golang
corsConfig := cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Type"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}


c.SetCookie("token", tokenString, int(expirationTime.Unix()), "/", "localhost", false, true)
```

fetch request on the frontend

```
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
```

Isn't the token supposed to be set on `localhost:8080`. This is the same in this video posted freecodecamp channel [React and Golang JWT Authentication](https://youtu.be/d4Y2DkKbxM0)

Data for the token

```
token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR...."
Domain:"localhost"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:true
Expires / Max-Age:"Thu, 11 Nov 2077 00:17:16 GMT"
SameSite:"None"
Secure:false
.
.
```

Comment: you are receiving the cookie in the response

Comment: At least one thing isn't right: `AllowOrigins: []string{"localhost"}` should be `AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"}`. FWIW, if you used [jub0bs/fcors](https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors) instead of Fiber's CORS middlware, the library would warn you that localhost is not a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) rather than silently returning a dysfunctional CORS middleware.

Comment: @jub0bs yep, you're right

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV The backend doesn't send the token in the response. It only sets the cookie

Comment: @blank1729 Perhaps of interest: https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors-examples/blob/main/fiber-v2/main.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A browser today shares cookies on localhost, regardless of the port." [link to discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28297#issuecomment-431626370)

Even though `localhost:8080` and `localhost:3000` are on different ports, they are both on the `localhost` domain on which the cookie is set. Hence we see the cookie `localhost:{port}` regardless of the port number

Comment: i think cookies are stored in browser local memory, irrespective of port number ?